# WebDriver element is returning false for isVisible/waitForForVisible

Tags: meteor, cucumber, webdriver-io, meteor-velocity

I am working on my first set of Cucumber tests in a Meteor app, but I cannot get the login step to work.  My app uses a custom login plugin I wrote specifically for this project.  Here is the step, as I currently have it defined with debug output:

```
this.Given(/^I am logged in as a\/an "([^"]*)"$/, function(roleName, callback) {
  this.browser
    .url(url.resolve(process.env.HOST, '/'))
    .waitForExist('#appSignIn');
  this.browser.getHTML('#appSignIn', function(err, html) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('err: ', err);
    } else {
      console.log('link HTML: ', html);
    }
  });
  this.browser.getCssProperty('#appSignIn', 'display', function(err, value) {
    console.log('link HTML display: ', value);
  });
  browser.isVisible('#appSignIn', function(err, isVisible) {
      console.log('#appSignIn', isVisible);
  });
  this.browser
    .waitForVisible('#appSignIn')
    .click('#appSignIn')
    .waitForExist('#username')
    .waitForVisible('#username')
    .setValue('#username', 'test' + roleName)
    .setValue('#password', 'test' + roleName)
    .leftClick('#signin')
    .waitForExist('#appSignOut')
    .waitForVisible('#appSignOut')
    .call(callback);
});
```

What I am seeing is in this logs is this:

```
 Scenario:                               # features/my.feature:11
    Given The server data has been reset  # features/my.feature:12
link HTML:  <a id="appSignIn" href="/signin">Sign In</a>
link HTML display:  { property: 'display',
  value: 'block',
  parsed: { type: 'ident', string: 'block' } }
#appSignIn false
    And I am logged in as a/an "ADMIN"    # features/my.feature:13
      RuntimeError: RuntimeError
           (ScriptTimeout:28) A script did not complete before its timeout expired.
           Problem: Timed out waiting for asyncrhonous script result after 511 ms
```

Basically, I see the HTML output, so I know the element is there.  I see the CSS is set to `display: block`, but then WebDriver reports the element is not visible with the isVisible, and similarly times out with the `waitForVisible` call.  the "Sign In" link is part of a Bootstrap collapsible nav-bar, located in the upper-right.

Comment: Couple of things to try that might help. Yet adding a pause for say 3 second to be sure it's not a wait issue (doesn't look like it) and also try to saveScreenshot as that sometimes helps. If the area is clipped by the view, it will not be visible but it works be in the HTML/css source.

Comment: 2 questions: 1. How do you start your tests? 2. from where do you get the `this.browser`?

Comment: Heh, this was from more than 2 years ago...I am not even sure what project I was working on at the time, TBH.  Also, from the looks of it, I figured out the issue was the browser size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was simple:  The default size of the viewport was too small, which was causing the Bootstrap nav element to collapse.  I set the browser size to 1000x600 and it worked as expected.