# Assert element doesn't exist in Cucumber w/ Meteor

Tags: meteor, cucumber, chai, meteor-velocity

I am new to Cucumber, and trying to write some simple tests to get started.  One thing I want to test is if an element is not on the page.

In my code I do:

```
var myBrowser = this.browser;
menu_data.hashes().forEach(function(menuItem, idx, items) {
  myBrowser
    .isExisting('#' + menuItem.anchor_id, function(err, isExisting) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      } else {
        isExisting.should.is.isfalse;
      }
    });
});
```

Everything I have tried testing `isExisting` has failed.  I tried using `assert.isfalse(isExisting)`, but I get an error saying assert is not there.  In fact, when I try to use any methods, like `should.assert.toFalse(isExisting)` throws an error saying `toFalse` doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

My bad. Have you tried `should.be(false)`

---

This is due to view port being too small.

Duplicate of this [WebDriver element is returning false for isVisible/waitForForVisible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880189/webdriver-element-is-returning-false-for-isvisible-waitforforvisible)

Comment: The question you linked to was one I posted about an unrelated issue. And no the viewport is not too small.  The viewport is currently set to 1000x600.  The other question was not dealing with `isExisting()`, it was dealing with `isVisible` and the fact that Bootstrap was causing the nav bar to collapse.